# How do I grab a column from table B if it that column may or may not be there?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table A:

```
| id | type   | name
| 1  | Person | Fred
| 2  | Animal | Rover
| 3  | Animal | Snowball
| 4  | Person | Mary
```

Table B:

```
| id | city
| 1  | NYC
| 4  | Charlotte
```

What I want:

```
| id | type   | name     | city
| 1  | Person | Fred     | NYC
| 2  | Animal | Rover    | NULL
| 3  | Animal | Snowball | NULL
| 4  | Person | Mary     | Charlotte
```

In other words, Table A is a table of People and Animals. Table B is a table of the cities people live in. I would like to (In a single query, if possible) get every result from Table A and, if it's a person, get that person's city in Table B. Is that possible in a single query? If not, what is the fastest way?

I've tried to do a simple join (e.g. "SELECT * FROM tableA,tableB WHERE tableA.id==tableB.id"), but doing that only gets the results of the people and not the animals.

thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` on this

```
SELECT  a.*, b.city
FROM    tableA a
        LEFT JOIN tableB  b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b21ff/1)

*and assuming that **only** person has records on `tableB`*

Comment: @Mr.Gaga assuming that only person has records on `tableB`. but if not, see this query how to filter only by `person` [*SQLFiddle Demo (please click here)*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c30b/5 "created link by John Woo")